# Compute correlation between two random variables

Tags: probability, correlation

A coin is flipped 100 times. Let $X$ be the number of heads in the first 70 flips and $Y$ the number of heads in the last 50. Compute the correlation of $X$ and $Y$.

Here's my attempt: $\rho=\frac{cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}=\frac{E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]}{\sqrt{70(.5)(.5)*50(.5)(.5)}}=\frac{5-35(25)}{\sqrt{218.75}}=\frac{-870}{14.8}=-58.8.$

But that's obviously not right because $0 \le \rho \le 1.$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Try computing $E(XY)$ again.

Comment: Isn't $E(XY)$ the number of times both coins are heads in the 20 flips that overlap?

Comment: I think I fixed it. But I'm still way off.

Comment: No, $E(XY)$ is the expectation of the product of $X$ and $Y$.  Note that $XY$ could be as small as zero and as large as $50\times 70$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U, V, W$ be the number of heads in the first $50$, the next $20$, and the last $30$. Then $X=U+V$ and $Y=V+W$. We have
$$E(XY)=E(UV)+E(UW)+E(V^2)+E(VW).$$
Three of the terms are easy to evaluate, using independence. For $E(V^2)$, the easiest way is to use the fact that $\text{Var}(V)=E(V^2)-(E(V))^2$.

Comment: Isn't it easier to say $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=\text{Cov}(U,V)+\text{Cov}(U,W)+\text{Cov}(V,V)+\text{Cov}(V,W) = \text{Var}(V)$ ?